# How to add a user without knowing the encrypted form of the password?

Tags: linux, unix, user-management, sles, user-accounts

I use the following command to create a user in a linux machine:

`useradd -d /home/dummy -g idiots -m -p 12345689 dummy`

The user is created and the home directory as well.
The problem is that I can not log-in to the system using this account since the `-p` expects the encrypted password returned by `crypto`.

**Question**:I want to create a user via a bash script and I don't know the encrypted password by `crypto`. How can I do it so that I am able to create this user automatically via a script and get arround the problem with the password?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use openssl to generate pre encrypted password strings to use with the -p option to useradd

```
echo "P4sSw0rD" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin

$1$Jxmpx1Da$Y8MzBctIyDW8/7pFPbNWD1
```

The `-1` says to generate a MD5 password hash. The salt is automatically generated.

You can then use

```
useradd -d /home/dummy -g idiots -m -p $(echo "P4sSw0rD" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) dummy
```

to add the user. To do this interactively hiding the password

```
useradd -d /home/dummy -g idiots -m -p $(read -sp Password: pw ; echo $pw | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) dummy
```

Comment: Is openssl command available in ALL linux installations by default?Can I count on it?

Comment: Also `echo` will show the password in the console.How can I avoid this?

Comment: @Jim: If not all, then 99%. It's part of the SSH client and server packages, so it's almost always installed, though technically I don't believe it's required. You can count on it being installed by default, but not necessarily that someone has not uninstalled it.

Comment: @Jim: Couldn't say with 100% certainty it'll be on _all_ linux installations.

Comment: @Iain:What about `echo`?How can I avoid that?

Comment: @Jim: See my update

Comment: @Iain:Could you please explain more on `-p` part?I am not very good with bash scripts

Comment: It tells read not to display a prompt in this case Password:

Comment: @Iain:I see that it prompts for password from user.I don't understand how `$(read -sp Password2: pw echo $pw | openssl passwd -1 -stdin)` works.I mean the part before the pipe

Comment: @Iain:When I run your command I get `Password:useradd: Too few arguments.`

Comment: @Jim: fixed a typo.

Comment: If you are using echo, you probably need a `-n` so you don't encrypt the trailing newline as well:  `echo -n "P4sSw0rD" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin`

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script), you can use

```
echo "password" | passwd dummy --stdin
```

I've never tried this.

Alternatively, you could put the user's public key in `/home/dummy/.ssh/authorized_keys` and forget about passwords entirely.  This is the best option security-wise.

Comment: `echo` will show the password in the console.How can I avoid this?

Comment: You could put the password in a file and use `cat passwordfile | passwd dummy --stdin` or `passwd --stdin dummy < passwordfile`.  On another note, I just tested this `--stdin` option on a Ubuntu box and it did not work.  The version of `passwd` I have doesn't support that option.  Yours may not either.  One of the other answers using `chpasswd`, `openssl` or `newusers` might be better if you *must* have passwords.

Answer (score 3):

That`s how I do it:

```
# cat user-pw_list
john:p455W0rD
geany:p455W0rD


# cat CreateUsers.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# filename: CreateUsers.sh
# usage: cat "User:passwd" | $0
#
set -e
# set -x
while read ; do
  USER=${REPLY%%:*}
  PWD=${REPLY##*:}
  # alternative for random passwd, where $RANDOM is a bash function
  #PWD=${REPLY%%:*}$RANDOM$RANDOM

  echo -e "adding User $USER "
  # for disabled users: /usr/sbin/nologin, otherwise /bin/bash
  /usr/sbin/useradd -c automaticUser -m -k/dev/null -s /usr/sbin/nologin $USER
  echo "$USER:$PWD" | chpasswd --md5 $USER

  ## also add user to samba:
  #echo -e "$PWD\n$PWD" | pdbedit -t -u $USER
done
```

Comment: Could you please explain this solution?I am not very good with bash scripts

Answer (score 2):

As you are going to use a bash script, perhaps the good old `newusers` command would be helpful to you? It reads its input from a text file formatted like this:

```
pw_name:pw_passwd:pw_uid:pw_gid:pw_gecos:pw_dir:pw_shell
```

And the password in that file should be clear text. You can list as many users as you wish in the input file.

For more information see `man newusers`.

Comment: I get:`bash: newusers: command not found` and `No manual entry for newusers`

Comment: Oh, so SLES does not bundle `newusers` (by default), even though Fedora, Debian and RHEL seem to do so.