# responding to a double password prompt with Fabric

Tags: ubuntu, python, fabric

I'm using this Fabric function to try to add a user to a Ubuntu server. It's not throwing an error, but I can't login with the user that I'm trying to add after the script's finished. If I add a user manually, after I run the `adduser myusername` command, I get prompted twice to enter a password. In this script, the repeated prompt (as I call it) is being dealt with (uneffectively, I believe) by passing the password twice to this echo command

```
 if not sudo("adduser %s | echo -e '%s\n%s\n'" % (new_user,passwd,passwd)).failed:
```

Can you explain how that would more appropriately be dealt with in this function?

```
def user_add(new_user, passwd=False):
    """Add new user"""
    with settings(hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr'), warn_only=True):
        # if is_host_up(env.host):
        if not passwd:
                passwd = generate_passwd()
            if not sudo("adduser %s | echo -e '%s\n%s\n'" % (new_user,passwd,passwd)).failed:
                run('echo "{user} ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers'.format(user=new_user))
                ...other code not included
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adduser` is just a Debian/Ubuntu-specific front-end to the more normal `useradd` command, which takes a variety of options on the command line, including a pre-hashed password as its `-p` option. For this you should probably be calling `useradd` with the desired options instead of `adduser`.

On most other Linux distributions, `adduser` is simply symlinked to `useradd`, or absent entirely.

Comment: Thanks, this might come in handy for anyone else reading the question/answer http://serverfault.com/questions/367559/how-to-add-a-user-without-knowing-the-encrypted-form-of-the-password